# Opening and searching dBase III (DBF) databases in Python

Tags: python, dbf

I'm looking to develop an application in python which needs to search through a dBase III database file (DBF).  I've been searching for a while now, but I cannot find any good documentation on how to do this.  I've tried using DBFpy but cannot find any documentation on how to index/search a column.  I've also tried to follow the advice in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373086/python-fast-querying-in-a-big-dbf-xbase-file) but apparently my DBF file is "closed."  I looked at the calls [listed here](http://packages.python.org/dbf/) but could not determine how to "open" the file.  Could anyone recommend a python module for working with DBF files with documentation or instruct me how to properly use other DBF python modules.  Thanks!

Comment: Just determined how to open the database file ... stupid of me but it's 'table.open()'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [my dbf module](http://python.org/pypi/dbf) the basic flow is something like:

```
import dbf

some_table = dbf.Table('/path/to/table.dbf')  # table is closed
some_table.open()
index = some_table.create_index(record_indexer)
.
.
.
records = index.search(match=(some_value,))   # returns a dbf.List of matching records
```

and `record_indexer` is a function that returns the appropriate index value; it can be as simple as

```
lambda rec: rec.desired_field
```

or as complex as you need:

```
def record_indexer(record):
    if record.that_field == 'bad value':
        return dbf.DoNotIndex             # record is ignored
    return record.this_field, record.other
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed reply.  Within "record_indexer", I should set "desired_field" to a column header within the database, correct?  As far as I can gather, the options in my database are MEM_ID, MEM_NAME, EXPIRED, STATE, ... When I enter the command "index = some_table.create_index(lambda rec: rec.MEM_ID)" I catch a dbf.FieldMissingError: 'MEM_ID: no such field in table'. Is there a way using your dbf module to list the available fields.  Thanks again so much for your time.

Comment: @StanleySwitalski: I'll try and get some decent docs together this week.  All field names are lower case, you want `rec.mem_id`.  `table.field_names` returns a list of all the fields; `print table` gives all the meta-data in human readable format; `table.structure()` returns a list appropriate for creating another identical table.

Comment: Thanks so much. Because I'm working on a Mac and this database is so large, I never had the opportunity to open the DBF properly. Instead I opened it in Excel and it presented the column names in all caps.  That's why I assumed it was meant to be in all caps.  This is a big hurdle crossed for me.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have been scratching my head trying the figure out why the table is 'CLOSED'...