# Reading a .dat file in Python with potentially empty columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, file-io

I am trying to read a .DAT file in Python. This .DAT file is part of a group of files, which can be loaded into Google Maps (so it has a `.ID`, `.MAP`, `.IND`, and a `.TAB` file associated with it).

Opening it in Notepad, my file looks like: [Dat File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOHzw.png), Additionally, I have uploaded the dat file from this link: https://filedropper.com/d/s/T0kpe8vHYcsP0swu2CZB30K7UZpB99

I am trying to parse this file into a readable Pandas dataframe. After analyzing the file, it seems that there are 4 columns (RecAreaNam, RecAreaCat, Province, and Comments-typically blank). For example, if you look at the second line:

`Whistler           World Class               BC             Tofino Ucluelet...`

There is a lot of spaces in between these columns, but after "BC" (the province column), Tofino Ucluelet would be part of a new row, not in comments.

I don't have much experience with reading DAT files in python, so what I tried is to research similar questions asked on StackOverFlow.

---

What I attempted:

1. Attempted to read it into Pandas:

```
s=pd.read_csv('CanHwyBuffer.DAT', header=None, lineterminator='\n')
```

Error: `pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 2, saw 11021`

2. `datContent = [i.strip().split() for i in open('CanHwyBuffer.DAT', encoding='latin1').readlines()]`

Can anyone suggest something that could remove the extra space, and make a dataframe out of this file?

Answer (score 1):

This file seems to be in dBase III DBF format:

```sh
$ file /tmp/RecAreaPolygons.DAT 
/tmp/RecAreaPolygons.DAT: FoxBase+/dBase III DBF, 165 records * 232, update-date 118-4-25, at offset 161 1st record "Whistler"
```

You should use a proper parser instead of trying to read it yourself. Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14008534/opening-and-searching-dbase-iii-dbf-databases-in-python) you could use the Python [`dbf` module](http://python.org/pypi/dbf). The data seems to have a strange encoding and contains a lot of null bytes which have to be cleaned up:

```py
import dbf
table = dbf.Table('/tmp/RecAreaPolygons.DAT')
table.open()

data = []
for record in table:
    try:
        data.append([record[fieldname].rstrip('\x00') for fieldname in table.field_names])
    except Exception as e:
        print('unable to decode record', e)
```

This will yield 164 records (skipping one due to a `UnicodeDecodeError`). You can then convert this into a DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=('RecAreaNam', 'RecAreaCat', 'Province', 'Comments'))
df.head()
```

gives

```
        RecAreaNam   RecAreaCat Province Comments
0         Whistler  World Class       BC         
1  Tofino Ucluelet  World Class       BC         
2            Banff  World Class       AB         
3          Canmore  World Class       AB         
4      Lake Louise  World Class       AB
```